# Monotone Convergence Theorem - by using indicator function

Tags: real-analysis

The following is my question.

Let $B_{n}$, $n≥1$ be an increasing sequence of events. Define $X_{n}(\omega)$ = $1_{B_{n}}(\omega)$, the indicator function of $B_{n}$. Set $B = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{n}$ and $X(\omega) = 1_{B}(\omega)$.

Explain why $X_{n}(\omega) ≤ X_{n+1}(\omega)$ for all $n ≥ 1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{n}(\omega) = X(\omega)$.

Use the Monotone Convergence Theorem to deduce that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(B_{n}) = \mathbb{P}(B)$.

I am having problem as I understood that $B_{n}$ is a subset of $B_{n+1}$. However, when we apply an indicator function to it, does it mean $X_{n+1}(\omega) = X_{n}(\omega) + 1_{B_{n+1}}(\omega)$? But this is different from the definition.

Comment: What makes you think that this equality is correct? Moreover, why do you even need it for this problem?

Comment: This is a bit disingenuous. "The" proof of the monotone convergence theorem relies on this special case for increasing chains of events. I strongly suspect you cannot make this noncircular. Though I guess it's still a good exercise